# Multiple indices in elastic search Index template

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have studied [Indices-templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/indices-templates.html) on elastic search website and I understood it. Now My requirement is that I want to apply same template on two indices. 
Suppose I have a template file : template_search.json and I want this template to be applied on two indices - index1_*, index2_*
So In this file, I have defined the template attribute in this template file as below:

```
"template" : "index1_*,index2_*"
```

But I am giving following validation error:

```
Error uploading template: {"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_index_template_exception","reason":"index_template [template_search] invalid, cause [Validation Failed: 1: template must not contain a ',';2: template must not container the following characters [\\, /, *, ?, \", <, >, |,  , ,];]"}],"type":"invalid_index_template_exception","reason":"index_template [template_search] invalid, cause [Validation Failed: 1: template must not contain a ',';2: template must not container the following characters [\\, /, *, ?, \", <, >, |,  , ,];]"}
```

I know one way of doing this, I can create  one separate file for each index. But then I will have the two different files with same data.

I have tried to search it on StackOverflow but didn't find any answer which can help me in solving it. Can somebody know how to define multiple indices in a single template file ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next major version of Elasticsearch (6.x) will support `index_patterns` as an array to fill this gap, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-templates.html

For 5.x you are stuck with creating more than one template for now (or use `index*`).

Comment: I am using - Elasticsearch(2.x), Is it possible with this version ?

Comment: no, this is only working with 6.x, but no versions below that. use the provided workaround in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

[Reference Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-templates.html)

```
 "index_patterns": ["te*", "bar*"],
```